# How does belt of giant strength interact with wildshape?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, wild-shape

Assume I have a belt of giant's strength +2 on a lvl 5 druid. Does the form I shape into also get +2 strength?

Answer (score 3):

## First Answer -- If not Wild-Clasped/Wilding, no

So, there is another layer to this question, which is this:

> Do my items work while I'm Wild Shaped?

The simple answer is, generally, no. Unless you get into things like Fangshields druids, Planar Shepherd, Master of Many Forms, or simply ape-ish forms (aka, any form that could feasibly wear the gear in the first place), most of them will not work while Wild-Shaped normally.

To make them work while Wild Shaped, you have to add either

1) Wilding Clasps from MIC (slotless, added to an item/slot, costs 4000 GP)

or

2) Wilding enchantment (only applicable to armor/shields/weapons, as far as I know).

A few druid-themed items will specifically state they work while Wild-Shaped (essentially having the Wilding quality), but Belt of Giant's Strength is not one of them.

## Second Answer -- If it IS Wild-Clasped/Wilding, YES!

So, the fact is that because you retain your type when Wild-Shaped, literally anything that worked for you while in normal form (aside from things you literally could not use like a dagger or something) will also work on your Wild-Shape.

This is why wilding-clasps are essentially item-taxes for Druids, and also why the MIC rules for combining items is such a HUGE deal for Druids, because it maximizes the amount of stuff they can cram into a few slots that will be wild-clasped.

If you Wild-Clasp something, though, the general answer is that it will absolutely work in Wild-Shape!

## As a bit of an addendum...

The SRD tells us that items you cannot use in Wild-Shape are either melded or dropped. If you assume a form that is humanoid...or a lot like a humanoid, chances are your items will be wearable.

The SRD also states that magic items can change size, so that's not a problem, thankfully.

In general, just think about the form, and use some logic. I love to play Planar Shepherds, which means most of my time is spent in Outsider forms. Now, some of these are really, really impossible to wear anything in, but most Outsiders are humanoid. Right now in a campaign I'm Wild-Shaped into a Kelvezu (type of demon).

In this case, my armor and cloak wouldn't be wearable because of my wings, but everything else would be wearable because the rest of the body isn't notably different from a Human (my character race). This means that some of the stuff I don't have wild-clasped, like my rod of lesser extension, are still hanging on my belt ready to be used. My armor and cloak are both wild-clasped, so they still work despite my wings.

If I were to take another favorite form, that of the Elder Viper Tree, then EVERYTHING would have to be melded unless it was wild-clasped/wilding because trees simply don't have shoulder slots, head slots, etc.

Comment: Unlike Alternate Form, Wild Shape melds all of your gear _even if_ your new shape could have worn it. (This clause is in the SRD, and was introduced in the same errata that made Wild Shape be based on Alternate Form.) Fangshields, Planar Shepherd, and MOMF  don't grant an exception to this either. And this rule isn't just a rare edge case, because most quadrupeds have all of the same item slots as humanoids; e.g. a wolf can still wear gloves, rings and bracelets on his paws (MIC p.219).

Comment: @topquark In the SRD, Wild Shaping *only* applies to animals, hence this reference -- in the eyes of the SRD/PHB, there AREN'T any forms that could wear gear normally (from my understanding of the MIC part you reference, in light of most other errata a wolf could wear those items, but it would be considered different slots....otherwise thinks like Gloves of Man wouldn't be necessary). Fanghsields, PlanShep, and MOMF all are from errata that was created later. In this case, I would interpret the Alternate Form analogy to be dominant since this is something beyond the scope of the SRD.